# Stop Activity from IntentService

Tags: android, android-activity, intentservice

I want to create a simple login in my application. From the `SignInActivity`, where user types his credentials, I start `IntentService`, which sends data to the server and obtains information about whether credentials are right or not. Errors, wrong credentials etc. are handled by `onDestroy()` method in my `IntentService` (for example `Toast` is displayed). I want to start another activity from this service, and also destroy the old one `SignInActivity`. Unfortunately I haven´t found anything helpful, could somebody help me? Thanks for you response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send a `Broadcast` from your `Service` to your `Activity` to indicate successful login and from the `Activity` start the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your login activity A and the second Activity you're calling from this B. So, you can close A from B like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412297/closing-one-activity-from-another/14412298#14412298).